# Remove language from Windows 10 using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-10

I want to use Powershell to add or remove a language and change the keyboard layout from left to right or from right to left in Windows 10. I wrote code to add a language but I cannot find a guide to remove it again or to change the layout. I also want to ask the user if he wants to add or to remove a language.

This is my code:

```
$List = Get-WinUserLanguageList
$List.Add("lt-LT")
Set-WinUserLanguageList $List
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: "*I wrote the code to add a language but I cannot find a guide to remove it again*" - the same way you add it; get the list, change it to what you want it to be ([remove the thing you don't want](https://www.jonathanmedd.net/2014/01/adding-and-removing-items-from-a-powershell-array.html)) and set the new list.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler The problem is that *it's not an array*.  It's a `List<WinUserLanguage>`.  The `List.Remove()` method doesn't ever seem to work.  Try `$L = New-WinUserLanguageList lt-LT; $L.Remove('lt-LT');`  You'll still have `lt-LT` in the list.  Even if you call `$L.Remove([Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage]'lt-LT')` it won't remove it because `$L[0] -eq [Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage]'lt-LT'` is `false` even though `$L[0].GetType() -eq [Microsoft.InternationalSettings.Commands.WinUserLanguage]` is `true`. You have to make a new list.

Comment: @BaconBits that's not because it's a generic list, that's because the list doesn't contain strings when it comes back from `Get-WinUserLanguageList`, so `"lt-LT"` isn't in it, and because `-eq` compares by reference and your new obj is different to the one in the list. You don't have to make a new list. What you do have to do is get the thing you want to remove, in some way e.g. `$x.remove(($x|where-object languagetag -eq 'lt'))` or `$x.RemoveAt(1)`, where that has to depend on how you design the program and what it's going to ask the user.

Comment: I tried $list.Remove("lt-LT") and it did not work

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I managed to do this by using the index of the English language in the `$List` array in combination with the `Set-WinUserLanguageList` cmdlet.  I found it odd that I couldn't simply reverse the steps by using the `$list.remove("lt-LT")` method, as it returns `False`, so I set about recreating the list another way.

After you've added "lt-LT" to the list, I ran the first cmdlet again to see what we were working with:

```
$list = Get-WinUserLanguageList
```

Which returned an array with two objects.  `$list[0]` Returned

```
LanguageTag     : en-US
Autonym         : English (United States)
EnglishName     : English
LocalizedName   : English (United States)
ScriptName      : Latin script
InputMethodTips : {0409:00000409}
Spellchecking   : True
Handwriting     : False
```

and `$list[1]` returned

```
LanguageTag     : lt
Autonym         : lietuvių
EnglishName     : Lithuanian
LocalizedName   : Lithuanian
ScriptName      : Latin script
InputMethodTips : {0427:00010427}
Spellchecking   : True
Handwriting     : False
```

So what we needed to do was ensure that `Set-WinUserLanguageList` only got one of the inputs.  I ran the following and it set the Language list appropriately.

```
Set-WinUserLanguageList $($list[0])
```

And now only the appropriate list is returned when running `Get-WinUserLanguageList`

Comment: How can I remove the language then?

Comment: Run `$list = Get-WinUserLanguageList` then `Set-WinUserLanguageList $($list[0])` as stated above.

Comment: I have 3 languages English,Russians and Lithuanian I want to add and remove the Lithuanian one using that script. That solution add only one language

Comment: In that case you could create a new variable and set it equal to the two lists you want to keep.  If English and Lithuanian are 0 and 1 in the array, then you can use the following:  `$x = ($list[0], $list[1])` then `Set-WinUserLanguageList $x`

Comment: It worked fine, thanks.
Is it possible to combine the add and the remove in one script depends on user's answer ?

Comment: Probably.  You could create a function with a whole bunch of "switch" parameters, and then add or remove the language based on whether or not the switch is present.

Comment: Sure thing!  Post again if you run into any problems, or reach out if you have any questions

Comment: Amazing. Thanks!